# Best way to manage systemd "xxx.system" configuration file in git with my other code?

Tags: git, symlink, systemd

I have a git project (python based) under my **/home/<user>/projectFoo** folder containing my code for a system service.  I would like to keep my systemd **foo.service** file in git with the rest of my project code.  I'm thinking of creating a symlink in the **/etc/systemd/system** directory that points to my **/home/<user>/projectFoo/foo.service** definition file so that it will be git-managed.

Are there are permissions or other issues I should be worried about?  It is clear how to manage my code in git, but not system configuration files such as **foo.service**.  After some Google work I don't see how other people keep track of their xxx.service files.

Are symlinks cool or problematic?  Is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to test that using sys

Second, you might need to [enable the target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294887/7490):

```
systemctl enable /root/myservice.service
```

Actually, `systemctl enable` will also do `systemctl link` (which is the recommended way to create symlink in  `/etc/systemd/system`)

That being said, unless your service file is changing on a daily basis, I would rather rely on a script updating at regular interval a copy of that system file back to my dotfiles repository.